# After resetting user's password in Active Directory using C#, both old and new passwords are working

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory, windows-authentication, sspi

Below is the code which is being used to reset the password. 
 I want to stop this behavior. 
 Only new password should work. user should not be able to log in with old password.

```
             using (var search= new DirectorySearcher(dir))
                {
                    search.Asynchronous = false;
                    search.CacheResults = false;

                    dirSearch.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(objectClass=person)(name=" + UserName.Trim() + "))";

                    SearchResult result = dirSearch.FindOne();

                    if (result != null)
                    {
                        using (var entryUpdate = result.GetDirectoryEntry())
                        {

                            entryUpdate.Invoke("setpassword", new object[] { NewPassword });
                            entryUpdate.CommitChanges();

                            //entryUpdate.RefreshCache();

                        }
                    }
                    result = null;
                }
```

Comment: Can somebody help me on this?

Comment: You might want to ask on http://serverfault.com/ first because allowing more than one password in the first place seems special and likely not even possible. As far as I can tell it's not strictly possible in the first place, so you likely have something else going on. It's unlikely to be related to the c# calls, and the [call you are making](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746344(v=vs.85).aspx) makes no mention of multiple passwords or having to remove the old one first or something. You should at least check the return value, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only possible to have two different passwords at the same time when Active Directory replication is broken.  This is not actually a code issue.  The way to fix it is to determine where the AD replication is broken.  You can quickly check AD Health at a glance by running the command *repadmin /showrepl*.  If you see errors, then run *dcdiag /v* on any domain controllers showing errors in the output.  A new favorite tool of mine now to determine AD Health also is to run the PowerShell utility [ADHealthCheck](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Active-Directory-Health-709336cd).